# Finding time between two patterns

Tags: unix

I am new to unix and can someone help me with following query?

I have a deployment log file and there I wanted to search for two pattern (eg: started , completed ) and after getting the out put I just want to calculate and print the time taken between the started step and completed step

I tried a lot I’m able to print the the out put but unable to print the time taken between those steps

Thanks in advance,
Mahi

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample deployment log and at the starting line i am searching for "DeploymentStart" and, at the end of the line "DeploymentCompleted".
After printing this out put i want to calculate the time taken between deploymentStart time and DeployemntCompleted time.

us>InterimDeploymentStart1523623301227ETA0submittedCount3suppressedCount0listRejectedCount0<
/Pair>batchSplitRejectedCount0emailRendererRejectedCount0

Apr13 12:41:49,492 INFO  com.epsilon.deploymentStatusNotifier.util.DeploymentStatusNotificationConverter taskScheduler-2 - JobMessage createdcom.epsilon.common.jobs.model.JobMessage@530c458e
Apr13 12:41:49,488 INFO  com.epsilon.deploymentStatusNotifier.util.DeploymentStatusNotificationConverter taskScheduler-2 - JobMessage createdcom.epsilon.comm

JobMessage>de841c92-6682-4696-883c-3087a9194531HarmonyPipelinecompletedDeploymentCompleted1523623301227ETA0